# Pass jagged/multidimensional array to web api method

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, asp.net-web-api, jagged-arrays

Is it possible to pass a jagged array to a web API method? For example:

```
public IEnumerable<Object> Get([FromUri]int[][] jaggedArray)
```

How would I be able to to pass a value for `jaggedArray` in my web request? The parameter doesn't necessarily have to be `[FromUri]`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pass a single array and additionally what the dimensions should be?  That way the server could just reconstruct it

Comment: @JaredPar Passing an array of objects each with an `int[]` attribute would be possible. I just want to see if the more convenient solution of a multidimensional array is possible.

Comment: If the framework doesn't support it, you could always create a custom databinder.

Comment: It is more like [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

Comment: Does traditional forms-style list model-binding not work? E. g. can you pass "[0][0]=1,[0][1]=2,..."?

Comment: @L.B Thanks. I got mixed up with the PHP idea of multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The parameter can be passed using the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/api/endPoint?jaggedArray[0][]=406&jaggedArray[0][]=404&jaggedArray[1][]=405&jaggedArray[1][]=407
```

This causes a jagged array containing two arrays, each with two numbers (406 and 404 for the first, then 405 and 407 for the second,) to be received.