# Send bi-dimensional array from angular js to web API is returning 400 error

Tags: arrays, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have two solutions running on my desktop:
One is a web solution using angularjs and calling the other solution which is a web API based on MVC and both are written in vb.net. Everything is working perfectly except one thing: when I tried to send a  bi-dimensional I got below error:

> The request is invalid. The parameters dictionary contains an invalid
>   entry for parameter 'myBiDimenArray' for method
>   'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Calculate(System.String[,],
>   Int32)' in 'CustomAPI.TestController'. The dictionary contains
>   a value of type 'System.String[]', but the parameter requires a value
>   of type 'System.String[,]'."

Below is my code in angular js:

```
var myBiDimenArray = [
            [1, 6],
            [5, 2],
            [9, 10]
            ];

console.log(myBiDimenArray); // it logs the array correctly

return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: urlBase + "Calculate",   
            params: {
                myBiDimenArray: myBiDimenArray,
                intSize: 1,
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-ApiKey': 'test' ,
                'Authorization': 'Basic 123456'
            }
        });
```

Below is my code in Web APi:

```
<HttpGet>
    Public Function Calculate(<FromUri> ByVal myBiDimenArray(,) As String, <FromUri> ByVal intSize As Integer) As IHttpActionResult
  ....
 End Function
```

I am new to this, I have searched for how to create  Bi-Dimen Array in vb.net and in JavaScript so I implemented the above in my solutions but error 400 is thrown and method is even not accessed.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

Below is my Routing in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
 name:="Test_Calculate", _
 routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{myBiDimenArray}/{intSize}", _
 defaults:=New With {.controller = "Test", .action = "Calculate"} _
)
```

PLease nte that:
If I send array of one dimension, method in API is accessed.
If I change the array definition in webApi to this: `myBiDimenArray()()` also method is accessed but array will be understood as array of one dimension

Comment: You should use `data` and `<FromBody>` instead of `params` and `<FromUri>` respectively

Comment: But this is a get method not Post

Comment: You should use post, how you going to send array via url?

Comment: So why if I send a 1 dimensional array it works?

Comment: May be there is some loophole, but with 2dimension array it is not work as you can see. Also can you give example of generated url with 1dimension array.

Comment: It's easy you have to repeat the array name with a new value each time you want to add a new item to it. `UrlBase/Test/Calculate?myOneDimenArray=1&myOneDimenArray=2&intSize=2` and his is an example of 2 dimin array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443463/pass-jagged-multidimensional-array-to-web-api-method

Comment: O my god, you think that is more convenient, than just to post array in request body?

Comment: I am not sending data to post it in database, I just need to retrieve some info that's why I thought it would be better if I send it through get method. Anyway thank you for your reply :) I will use post.